# One Page Horror Stories — Black and White Illustrations

Tags: story-identification, horror

As I recall, there was almost no text — just illustrations depicting a scene, and your imagination made up the rest.

One page I can clearly recall:  an empty bedroom with a crack in the ceiling.  There are *claws* coming out of the cracks....  Freaked me right out as a lad!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?  Check out the other [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/45487869-99-stories-of-blood-on-the-wall?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Tales-Horror-Alan-Riefe-Softcover/dp/B000VUCFVQ?

Comment: When were you a lad?

Comment: @Moriarty - I'm assuming it was after he was a nipper and slightly before he was a young fellow-me-lad

Answer (score -1):

The Mysteries of Harris Burdick by Chris Van Allsburg?

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE. Could you [edit] in some details to motivate why you think your answer is what the OP is looking for?

Comment: I looked through this one, and there are no pictures that match the description of claws coming through a crack in a ceiling.  (Or even any part of that.)